# Replacement/Alternative for Interface 'ClientDetails' in spring authorization server v. 1.0.0

Tags: java, spring, migration

We updated our project to use Spring Boot 3 together with Spring authorization server 1.0.0.

Therefore being a bit desperate after not having found any information about the above topic neither in Spring docs nor in Google (I might have done this completely wrong, though), I wanted to ask: what is the replacement of the above interface `ClientDetails` and its method `getAdditionalInformation`.

Before the upgrade we used something like:

```
Map<String, Object> additionalInformation = new HashMap<>();
var clientDetails = new BaseClientDetails();
clientDetails.setAdditionalInformation(additionalInformation);
clientDetails.setClientSecret("password);
clientDetails.setClientId("someClient");
clientDetails.setAuthorizedGrantTypes(Collections.singletonList(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD.getValue()));
clientDetails.setScope(Collections.singletonList("someScope"));
```

The only alternative way I have been able to find is to use `RegisteredClient`

```
RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient
          .withId("someClient")
          .clientSecret("password")
          .scope("someScope")
          .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
          .build();
```

But there is no builder method for setting the additional information. I could maybe use the method `clientSettings` and put the additional information there but it feels not really right to me.